# Only 2 friends are getting tagged - Facebook/Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my code. It does not show any errors but only the first 2 friends are tagged!

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($friendsID);$i++)
{
 $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$upload_photo['id']."/tags/".$friendsID[$i]."?access_token=".$token."&x=80&y=".$y."&method=POST";
 $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
 $post_url = urlencode($post_url);
 $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
 $y = $y + 53;
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than two friends?

Comment: Yup, i've, even the loops run for n times but only 2 friends are tagged .

Answer (score 1):

This is because The variable $x and $y should be les than 100 always, when you are running the loop their value increases 100 which causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the accounts you are trying to tag allow you to check them into places in their facebook account settings page.  How many friends are you expecting to be tagged?

Comment: i've 10 friends, but i can tag only 2 friends. And i can also tag 10 friends but at a time 2 only !